# Why does this sed command do nothing?

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I am trying to cat a file to create a copy of itself, but at the same time replace some values

my command is:

```
cat ${FILE} | sed "s|${key}|${value}|g" > ${TEMP_FILE}
```

However, when I open the temp file, none of the keys have been replaced- just a straight swap. I have echoed the values of key and value and they are correct - they come from an array element.

Yet if I use a plain string not a variable, it works fine for one type of key - i.e:

```
cat ${FILE} | sed "s|example_key|${value}|g" > ${TEMP_FILE}
```

The example_key instances within the file are replaced which is what I want.

However, when I try to use my array $key parameter, it does nothing. No idea why :-(

Command usage:

```
declare -a props
...
....
for x in "${props[@]}"
do
    key=`echo "${x}" | cut -d '=' -f 1`
    value=`echo "${x}" | cut -d '=' -f 2`


    # global replace on the $FILE
    cat ${FILE} | sed "s|${key}|${value}|g" > ${TEMP_FILE}
    #cat ${FILE} | sed "s|example_key|${value}|g" > ${TEMP_FILE}

done
```

array elements are stored in the following format:  $key=$value

Comment: Can you try: `sed "s~${key}~${value}~g" "${FILE}" > "${TEMP_FILE}"`

Comment: Can you write a [short, self-contained example](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: How does your _array_ look like?

Comment: edited question to consider remarks

Comment: quote the pipe between cat and sed and the file redirection after sed, and then echo the whole command from within your for loop to see what the commands are that are actually being executed.

Comment: Just be aware that this is doing an RE replacement not a string replacement AND what gets replaced could be affected by the order of the replacements since you might create a string to be replaced by an earlier replacement. Both situations make this a highly error-prone approach in general but it might be OK in your specific case depending on how much control you have over your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @BillKarwin for spotting the crux of the problem: each iteration of the loop wipes out the previous iterations' replacements, because the result of a *single* key-value pair replacement replaces the entire output file every time.

Try the following:

```
declare -a props

# ... 

cp "$FILE" "$TEMP_FILE"
for x in "${props[@]}"; do
  IFS='=' read -r key value <<<"$x"
  sed -i '' "s|${key}|${value}|g"  "${TEMP_FILE}"
done
```

- Copies the input file to the output file first, then replaces the output file *in-place* (using `sed`'s `-i` option) in every iteration of the loop.
- I also streamlined the code to parse each line into key and value, using `read`.
- Also note that I consistently double-quoted all variable references.
- @anubhava makes a good *general* point: depending on the variable values, a different regex delimiter may be needed (in your case: if the keys or values contained '|', you couldn't use '|' to delimit the regexes).

**Update**: @BillKarwin makes a good point: performing the replacements one by one, in a loop, is inefficient.

Here's a one-liner that avoids loops altogether:

```
sed -f <(awk -F'=' '{ if ($0) print "s/" $1 "/" substr($0, 1+length($1)) "/g" }' \
   "$FILE") "$FILE" > "$TEMP_FILE"
```

- Uses `awk` to build up the entire set of substitution commands for `sed` (one per line).
- Then feeds the result via process substitution as a command file to `sed` with `-f`.
- Handles the case where *values* have embedded `=` chars. correctly.

Answer (score 4):

```
key='echo "${x}" | cut -d '=' -f 1
value='echo "${x}" | cut -d '=' -f 2
```

Use back-ticks, not single-quotes, if you want to do command substitution.

```
key=`echo "${x}" | cut -d '=' -f 1`
value=`echo "${x}" | cut -d '=' -f 2`
```

Also note that as you loop over the series of `key=value` pairs, you're overwriting your temp file each time, using only one substitution applied to the original file.. So after the loop is finished, the best you can hope for is that only the last substitution will be applied.

---

I'd also suggest not doing this in multiple passes -- do it by passing multiple expressions to sed:

```
for x in "${props[@]}" ; do
  subst="$subst -e 's=$x=g'"
done
sed $subst "${FILE}" > "${TEMP_FILE}"
```

I'm using a trick, by using `=` as the delimiter for the sed substitution expression, we don't have to separate the key from the value.  The command simply becomes:

```
sed -e 's=foo=1=g' -e 's=bar=2=g' "${FILE}" > "${TEMP_FILE}"
```

Comment: Are I think that must be it, the fact it is overwriting each time. Any idea how I could get around that?

Comment: +1 for detecting the crux of the problem - the work of previous loop iterations getting wiped out by subsequent ones; the backtick issue no longer applies, though.

Comment: Re not replacing in a loop: great improvement; small caveat: if *values* have *embedded* `=` chars., the `sed` command will break. Mostly hypothetical point: by building up a potentially large command line (rather than feeding the commands via a file), you risk running into the max. command-line length.